# How do I order my x-axis on pandas bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, axis

Been struggling for a few days on a uni project I have to hand in in a week.
I'm working with a dataset (using pandas, mostly) and I have to anayze information about mountain expeditions.
My bar plots work fine but I still have the same issue every time: my x-axis is not in growing order, which isn't of the highest importance but it still bothers me.
I have been looking everywhere online but I can't find anything to fix my issue.
Here's my line of code:

```
expeditions['members'].value_counts().plot.bar(figsize=(12,8))
```

The column members just contains integers and represents how many people took part in each expedition. But here is what I get:
[image]

How do I order the x-axis in growing order? I realize this must be pretty simple but I just can't figure out how to do it; and I have the same issue with all my other graphs...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

`value_counts` sorts the values by descending frequencies by default. Disable sorting using `sort=False`:

```
expeditions['members'].value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(figsize=(12,8))
```

Or sort the index prior to plotting:

```
expeditions['members'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar(figsize=(12,8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting the index like this:

```
expeditions['members'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar(figsize=(12,8))
```

Answer (score 1):

*Just for illustration*

You need to `sort_values / value_counts` or `value_counts / sort_index` before your plot **as suggested by the two previous answers of @Bashton and @mozway**:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample
expeditions = pd.DataFrame({'members': np.random.randint(1, 10, 100)})

expeditions['members'].sort_values().value_counts(sort=False) \
                      .plot.bar(figsize=(12, 8), legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]